# error: unknown field ‘bulk_in_size’ specified in initializer

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to install a [driver](http://wiki.e1550.mobi/doku.php?id=troubleshooting#one_way_voice_on_huawei_e150), but it is giving me these errors. Why?

```
[root@localhost kmod-huawei-voice]# make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.i686/build M=/usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.i686'
  CC [M]  /usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice/option.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice/huawei_voice.o
/usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice/huawei_voice.c:113: error: unknown field ‘bulk_in_size’ specified in initializer
/usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice/huawei_voice.c:113: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
/usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice/huawei_voice.c:114: error: unknown field ‘bulk_out_size’ specified in initializer
/usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice/huawei_voice.c:114: warning: missing braces around initializer
/usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice/huawei_voice.c:114: warning: (near initialization for ‘huawei_voice_1port_device.driver_list’)
/usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice/huawei_voice.c:114: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice/huawei_voice.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/src/kmod-huawei-voice] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.i686'
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@localhost kmod-huawei-voice]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Jul 16 21:12:30 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likly you need older kernel or asterisk version(s). Note, driver was last modifed 3 years ago, after that kernel headers changed alot.